# Bounded faces of a planar path

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity

> Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a path.  Show that for two disjoint compact sets $K_1$ and $K_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, there are only finitely many components of $\gamma^c$ which intersect both $K_1$ and $K_2$.

Since $\gamma$ is continuous on a compact set it is uniformly continuous.  In contrapositive form, this says that for any $M>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|f(s)-f(t)|>M$, then $|s-t|>\delta$.  I believe that the result should follow from this fact.

**NOTE**: I posted a solution below for the special case where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are circles.  It seems much longer than necessary, I think there should be a short proof of the general result.

Comment: It does not follow from the continuity of the path?

Comment: @GiovanniSiclari Not directly, as far as I can tell.  Since it is not as though the boundary of a given component must be $\gamma(I)$ for some interval $I\subseteq[0,1]$.  In fact if $D$ is some component of $\gamma^c$, then $\gamma^{-1}$ of the boundary of $D$ might be some really terrible subset of $[0,1]$, I suppose.

Comment: I agree with you Trevor, I was referring to the "fact"

Comment: Is the validity of the fact unclear to you, or how it proves the result in your question? As Giovanni suggested, the fact does indeed follow from the continuity of $\gamma$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Sorry, I realize that the fact just is the definition of uniform continuity.  What was not clear to me was how the fact implied the result.  I now have some ideas that I will write up when I am able.

Comment: I am actually thinking about this problem, and I have an idea for a solution, but it requires you to show that the diameter of the bounded components (of which there are only countably many) converges to $0$. Once you have this, you can pick $x_i \in K_1\cap U_i$ and $y_i\in K_2\cap U_i$, where $(U_i)_i$ is a sequence of components intersecting both $K_1$ and $K_2$. Then $(x_i)_i,(y_i)_i$ cluster at points $x\in K_1,y\in K_2$, respectively, and it follows from the claim that $x=y$. So the claim that $\text{diam}(U_i)\to0$ remains to be shown. Maybe you could use uniform continuity for that.

Comment: My approach for a proof of the claim in my last comment was to use the fact that the image of $\gamma$ is locally connected, but I could not rule out all eventualities yet.

Comment: @StefanHamcke You can look at the at the proof I posted for a special case if you like.  It should generalize to the full result, though it might be a pain to not be able to use the orientation from the circles.  Anyway, I think there should be a short proof of the general result.

Comment: The argument in my second to last comment was a bit sloppy. What I meant is that when $d(x_i,y_i)_i \to 0$, then the set of cluster points of $(x_i)_i$ is the same as the set of cluster points of $(y_i)_i$, and since this set is in $K_1$ as well as in $K_2$, this means these sets are not disjoint. Also, I feel like I'm getting closer to finishing my proof that the diameter of the components of the complement of a locally connected compact set (like the image of $\gamma$) converges to $0$. I might also take a look at your answer. But now I'm tired, so I'll continue tomorrow or the next days.

Comment: @StefanHamcke I think that once we know that $diam(U_i)\to0$, we are done, and we need not choose any points $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$.  SInce $K_1$ and $K_2$ are compact, they are separated by some positive distance $\epsilon>0$.  That is, for all $x\in K_1$ and $y\in K_2$, $|x-y|>\epsilon$.  Therefore if for all $n>N$, $diam(U_n)<\epsilon$, then for all such $U_n$, $U_n$ cannot contain points in both $K_1$ and $K_2$.

Comment: Yes, that is a better way to finish the proof :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reduction of the general case to the one of two disjoint round circles (which you already know how to handle). Suppose that there exists a 
sequence $U_i$ of distinct components of $R^2 - Im(\gamma)$ each of which intersects both $K_1$ and $K_2$ nontrivially. Then, after passing to a subsequence (twice), by compactness of $K_1, K_2$, there exist points $x_j\in K_j, j=1,2$ such that 
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty} dist(x_j, cl(U_i))= 0, j=1,2$$
Now, since $x_1\ne x_2$,   there is a pair of disjoint closed round disks $B_1=B(x_1, r), B_2=B(x_2, r)$ such that each $U_i$ has nonempty intersection with both $B_1$ and $B_2$. By connectedness of $U_i$'s, each $U_i$ has nonempty intersection with each round circle $C_j=\partial B_j, j=1,2$.

Comment: Very nice.  I had thought of doing everything you wrote, but I did not put together that this would then reduce it to the circles case.

Answer (score 2):

Following is a solution for the case that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are circles.

For $r>0$, define $C_r$ to be the circle centered at the origin, with radius $r$.  By first applying a homeomorphism to the sphere, we may assume without loss of generality that $K_1=C_1$ and $K_2=C_2$.

Suppose by way of contradiction that there are infinitely many components of $\gamma^c$ which intersect both $C_1$ and $C_2$.  Since each component of $\gamma^c$ is open, there are only countably many of them.  Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of the components of $\gamma^c$ which intersect both $C_1$ and $C_2$.  Since each $E_i$ is open and connected in $\mathbb{C}$, it is also path connected.  Therefore for each $i$, we may define a path $\varphi_i:[0,1]\to E_i$ such that $\varphi_i(0)\in C_1$ and $\varphi_i(1)\in C_2$.  By restricting $\varphi_i$ if necessary, we may also assume that for each $t\in(0,1)$, $|\varphi_i(t)|\in(1,2)$.  Define $x_i=\varphi_i(0)$ and $z_i=\varphi_i(1)$.  Define $r_i\in(0,1)$ to be the smallest number such that $|\varphi_i(r_i)|=1.5$, and define $y_i=\varphi_i(r_i)$.

It is immediate from their definition that, for any $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$, if $i\neq j$, then $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_j$ are distinct from each other.  Since they do not cross in the region $\{z:1<|z|<2\}$, it follows that the orientation of the $x_i$ around $C_1$ is the same as the orientation of the $z_i$ around $C_2$ and the $y_i$ around $C_{1.5}$.  That is, for any distinct $i,j,k\in\mathbb{N}$, if $x_i,x_j,x_k$ is the order in which the points appear when $C_1$ is traversed with positive orientation, then $z_i,z_j,z_k$ is the order in which those points appear when $C_2$ is traversed with positive orientation, and $y_i,y_j,y_k$ is the order in which those points appear when $C_{1.5}$ is traversed with positive orientation.

Since $\gamma$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,1]$, it is uniformly continuous, therefore we may choose a $\delta>0$ such that for any $s,t\in[0,1]$, if $|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)|>1/4$, $|s-t|>\delta$.  Choose an $N>0$ such that $N\delta>1$.  By reordering the elements described above, we may assume that the points $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N$ appear in precisely this order as $C_1$ is traversed with positive orientation.  For the remainder of the proof, addition is done modulo $N$.

For each $i$, let $F_i$ denote the domain which is bounded by the paths $\varphi_i$, $\varphi_{i+1}$, the arc of the circle $C_1$ with end points $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ which does not contain $x_{i+2}$, and the arc of the circle $C_2$ with end points $z_i$ and $z_{i+1}$ which does not contain $z_{i+2}$.  Since $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ are in different faces of $\gamma$, the arc of $C_{1.5}$ with end points $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ which does not contain $y_{i+2}$, must intersect $\gamma$.  Since this arc is contained in $F_i$, we may choose a point $\alpha_i\in\gamma\cap F_i$ such that $|\alpha_i|=1.5$.  Define $s_i\in(0,1)$ to be the smallest number such that $\gamma(s_i)=\alpha_i$.  Define $t_i\in(s_i,1)$ to be the smallest number (if one exists) such that $\gamma(t_i)\in\partial F_i$ (if no such number exists, choose $t_i\in(0,s_i)$ to be the largest such that $\gamma(t_i)\in\partial F_i$).  Define $\beta_i=\gamma(t_i)$.  Let $J_i$ denote the interval in $[0,1]$ with end points $s_i$ and $t_i$ (that is, either $[s_i,t_i]$ or $[t_i,s_i]$).

The point $\beta_i\in\partial F_i$ must be in either $C_1$ or $C_2$, since the portion of $\partial F_i$ which is not in either $C_1$ or $C_2$ (namely $\varphi_i$ and $\varphi_{i+1}$) is contained in $\gamma^c$.  Thus it follows that $|\gamma(s_i)-\gamma(t_i)|>1/4$, and thus $\lambda(J_i)>\delta$.  Note that for any distinct $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, since $F_i$ and $F_j$ are disjoint, $\gamma(J_i)$ and $\gamma(J_j)$ are disjoint, and thus $J_i$ and $J_j$ are disjoint.  We thus have that $\{J_i\}$ is a sequence of disjoint intervals in $[0,1]$, giving us the contradiction $$1=\lambda([0,1])\geq\sum_{i=1}^N\lambda(J_i)\geq\sum_{i=1}^N\delta=N\delta>1.$$

This concludes the proof.